# Change Admin menu placement using hooks

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, admin-menu

I have been working in a wordpress multisite installation. Where I am using upPrev plugin that has an option page under Appearance ->> upPrev

Now what I need is to move this menu under Settings ->> upPrev without editing the core plugin file. Here is the code used to register the menu in upPrev.php :

```
          add_action( 'admin_menu',                 'iworks_upprev_add_pages' );

    function iworks_upprev_add_pages()
    {
    $dir = explode('/', dirname(__FILE__));
    $dir = $dir[ count( $dir ) - 1 ];
    if (current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && function_exists('add_theme_page') ) {
        add_theme_page(
            __('upPrev', 'upprev'),
            __('upPrev', 'upprev'),
            'manage_options',
            $dir.'/admin/index.php'
        );
    }
}
```

I've tried using the code below to update menu :

```
  add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_tp', 999 );

function my_remove_tp() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'upprev/admin/index.php' );
}


add_action('admin_menu', 'upprev_menu');
function upprev_menu(){
        //add_options_page('upPrev Menu', 'upPrev', 'manage_options', 'upprev/admin/index.php', 'upprev');  
        if (current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && function_exists('add_options_page') ) {
    add_options_page(
        __('upPrev', 'upprev'),
        __('upPrev', 'upprev'),
        'edit_page', 'options-general.php?page=upprev/admin/index.php');
    }
}
```

Result : The menu is showing under settings but leads to an empty page...
Any idea how it can be fixed ??

Comment: I am using the code in wp-content/mu-plugins/custom-plugin/cplugin.php

Comment: Please use the edit link instead of comments. And please also rework your post as the code styling didn't work out. There're WYSIWYG buttons for that.

Comment: My site is in maintenance mode... And as it is an admin side issue, so I thunk posting code is perfect thing..

Comment: I meant the WYSIWYG editor here on this site - to format your question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it... Posting the solution here if it helps someone...
Here is the final code that fixed my problem :

```
/** Remove the Menu registered by Plugin **/
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_tp', 999 );
```

```
function my_remove_tp() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'upprev/admin/index.php' );
}
```

/** Re-Register the menu from here **/
add_action('admin_menu', 'upprev_menu2');

function upprev_menu2(){
add_options_page('upPrev Menu', 'upPrev', 'manage_options', 'upprev/admin/index.php', '');
}